# batch script how to create a string out of different variable parts

Tags: batch-file, replace

in my company we create software for different customers to handle our machines. As each product is unique, so is the control software, but not completely new. So for a start we copy an old project, rename it and change it until it fits.
Usually the directory name is the name for the new program (our ide uses the directory name, but also relies on some other files following the same name scheme).
For the renaming I've wrote a short batch script which finds the old name scheme and retrieves from the directory name the new one.
But the only solution I've found for this uses a new batchfile for each file to be renamed.
Is there a better way to get the content of !progNeu! ?

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
set pfad=%CD%
for /d %%A in (%pfad%) do (set progNeu=%%~nxA)
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=|" %%B in ('dir /b *.s19 ^| findstr /v "appl"') > do (
    set progAlt=%%B
    set rumpfAlt=!progAlt:.s19=!
    >x ECHO !rumpfAlt!&FOR %%C IN (x) DO SET /A strlength=%%~zC - 2&del x
    for %%D in (!rumpfAlt!*.*) do (
        set progAlt=%%D
        >x.bat  echo @echo off
        >>x.bat echo set ausg=!progAlt!
        >>x.bat echo echo %%ausg:~!strlength!%%

        for /f "" %%E in ('x.bat') do (
            set "dateiNeu=!progNeu!%%E"
            if exist !dateiNeu! del !dateiNeu!
            rename %%D !dateiNeu!
        )
        del x.bat
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have not missed something, this could be the equivalent to your code

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "pfad=%CD%"

    for /d %%A in ("%pfad%") do (
        for /f "delims=" %%B in ('
            dir /b *.s19 ^| findstr /v "appl"
        ') do for %%D in ("%%~nB*.*") do (
            set "progAlt=%%D"
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            for %%E in ("!progAlt:%%~nB=!") do (
                endlocal
                echo move /y "%%D" "%%~nxA%%~E"
            )
        )
    )
```

I have removed almost all the inner variables that are simply using the values that the `for` replaceable parameters already hold, and used the adecuated modifiers to retrieve the needed part from the file names.

Comment: Hello MC ND
when I remove the "echo" from

Comment: echo move /y "%%D" "%%~nxA%%~E"
it does exactly what it should. I'm a little surprised, cause I'm not very familiar with batch concept of "FOR" loops. To use a loop to get a single command processed is strange. 
But why did you set     setlocal [...] disabledelayedexpansion
in the second row to switch it back on later?

Comment: @Mecki, To do the substring replacement delayed expansion is needed (set and read the same variable inside a code block), but if I set a variable to the result of the substring operation with delayed expansion enabled, if there is any `!` in the value, it will be removed by the parser trying to expand variables. To prevent this, delayed expansion is enabled only when needed, the result of the operation is captured inside a `for` replaceable parameter and delayed expansion is disabled before using the value. Not knowing if the file names/paths include any `!`, this is a safe way of coding it.

Comment: understood :-)
you did not remove the set commands for "pfad" and "progAlt" in the code. Do you know why it isn't possible to use "%%D:%%~nB=" instead of "!progAlt:%%~nB=!" (it does not work - I tried)?

Comment: @Mecki, substring operations are only available in variables. `for` replaceable parameters don't allow it. Just syntax. Use `set /?` and `for /?` to list what can be done.

Comment: ok! As I said 'FOR' in batch is new to me. Thanks for your help!!